# Read Localisation Resource files set from Project output directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization

I want to read my resource files from debug folder and i using below way i.e first i convert the Resource file name i.e. **XML to binary resource file** with(**Test.fi-FI.resx to Test.fi-FI.resources**)
I placed all the resource binary files under one folder

```
public string ReadResourceValue(string file, string key)
        {
            //value for our return value
            string resourceValue = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                string resourceFile = file;

                // string filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
                string filePath = @"C:\Program Files\ResourceSet\Test.resources";

                ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile, filePath, null);

                resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(key);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){ }

            return resourceValue;
        }
```

**ReadResourceValue("Test", "fi-FI");**

But above code is not picking any resource set.Please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: I think you are over-thinking this problem.  What tutorials have you read that makes you think this is the correct way of accessing translations?

Comment: @Neil https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5447/NET-Localization-using-Resource-file    Mentioned under point b...also you can check the msdn wensite

Comment: @Neil any suggestions or any another idea..please let me know if i am unable to explain.. ?

Comment: OK, so you are reading a 14 year old article based on .net 1.1 !!!  Things have moved on since then.  What version of asp.net are you targeting?

Comment: @Neil i am targeting 4.5.2 framework

Comment: OK, so try the official documentation first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx

Comment: googling => how to read a localization dictionary in asp.net

 1 - [ASP.NET MVC Localization using a Database](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1092297/ASP-NET-MVC-Localization-using-a-Database)

 2 - [Asp.net Core localization with json files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43615912/5605739)

 3 - [ASP.NET MVC Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6036653/5605739)

 4 - [ASP.NET MVC Retrieve localized resources programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32746942/5605739)

Comment: @CelsoLívero thanks for your help but above urls are bit off track according to above posted problem